# how to support latout file in multiple screen size

Tags: android, layout

```
    Issue:
     **how to create layout support all screen size** 
   values
   values-sw320dp (... to 4'')
   values-sw480dp (5'' to 5,5'')
   values-sw600dp (7'' to 10'')
   values-sw720dp (10'' to ...)
   what should be the correct ratio above folder i have to use
```

https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 0):

Personally I suggest [sdp library](https://github.com/intuit/sdp)

Because this library manages all by itself you just have to pass the value for dimens for ex `@dimen/_50sdp` and this will manage all.

According to doc:

> This size unit scales with the screen size. It can help Android developers with supporting multiple screens.

Comment: that means there is no need to pass multiple values

Comment: and no need to create multiple values folder, only one dimen file is use is it

Comment: Yes exactly.Just integrate this library and if you are giving the 5dp margin in your layout for example then just use @dimen/_5sdp (all ctrl+space) ;) .

Comment: Just visit the link i provided and you will find your destination

Comment: Did you check it? @Chetna

Comment: in most cases still need to design a different layout for tablets in this library

Comment: @Chetna, yes but this lib surely lessen your effort,isn't it?